# telnet to weblogic managed server doesn't work on docker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm working with a weblogic image to create a multi-host environment with docker. I've gone through an [article](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleWebLogic/workshops/multihost) from oracle and created three docker machines **machine1, machine2 and machine3**. All the machines are part of a swarm network in which m1 is manager and other two are worker nodes. And then, I created a overlay network my-net.

```
docker network create --driver overlay --subnet=10.0.9.0/24 --attachable my-net
```

The **machine1** has the **Admin** container attached to the swarm network.

```
docker run -d --name admin --env-file /DockerBaseImage/configurations/domain.properties -v /DockerBaseImage/configurations/:/configurations -v /DockerBaseImage/applications/:/applications  -p 9005:8001 --net my-net 12212-baseimage
```

And the machine2 and machine3 has ManagedServer2 and ManagedServer3 respectively.

```
docker run -d --name ManagedServer1--env-file /DockerBaseImage/configurations/domain.properties -v /DockerBaseImage/configurations/:/configurations -v /DockerBaseImage/applications/:/applications --link admin:wlsadmin --env NM_NAME=Machine2 --env MS_NAME=ManagedServer2  -p 9002:7002  --net my-net 12212-baseimage createServer.sh

docker run -d --name ManagedServer2--env-file /DockerBaseImage/configurations/domain.properties -v /DockerBaseImage/configurations/:/configurations -v /DockerBaseImage/applications/:/applications --link admin:wlsadmin --env NM_NAME=Machine3 --env MS_NAME=ManagedServer3  -p 9002:7002  --net my-net 12212-baseimage createServer.sh
```

Now when I login to weblogic console I can see all the three servers running but, when I do **telnet machine2 9002** from machine1 I get connection refused message. What could I be doing wrong?

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.2-generic

ARG ADMIN_PASSWORD
ARG ADMIN_NAME
ARG DOMAIN_NAME
ARG ADMIN_PORT
ARG CLUSTER_NAME
ARG DEBUG_FLAG
ARG PRODUCTION_MODE

# WLS Configuration (editable during runtime)
# ---------------------------
ENV ADMIN_HOST="wlsadmin" \
    NM_PORT="5556" \
    MS_PORT="7002" \
    DEBUG_PORT="8453" \
    CONFIG_JVM_ARGS="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true"

# WLS Configuration (persisted. do not change during runtime)
# -----------------------------------------------------------
ENV DOMAIN_NAME="${DOMAIN_NAME:-basedomain}" \
    DOMAIN_HOME=/domains/${DOMAIN_NAME:-basedomain} \
    ADMIN_NAME="${ADMIN_NAME:-AdminServer}" \
    ADMIN_PORT="${ADMIN_PORT:-8001}" \
    CLUSTER_NAME="${CLUSTER_NAME:-DockerCluster}" \
    debugFlag="${DEBUG_FLAG:-false}" \
    PRODUCTION_MODE="${PRODUCTION_MODE:-prod}" \
    PATH=$PATH:/u01/oracle/oracle_common/common/bin:/u01/oracle/wlserver/common/bin:/domains/${DOMAIN_NAME:-basedomain}/bin:/u01/oracle

# Add files required to build this image
ADD resources/* /u01/oracle/
ADD *.jar /u01/oracle/wlserver/common/templates/wls/
ADD configurations/ /configurations
ADD applications/ /applications

USER root

RUN mkdir /domains/ && \
    chown -R oracle /domains/

USER oracle
RUN /u01/oracle/wlst /u01/oracle/create-wls-domain.py && \
    mkdir -p $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security && \
    echo "username=weblogic" > $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties && \
    echo "password=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-weblogic1}" >> $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties && \
    echo ". $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setDomainEnv.sh" >> /u01/oracle/.bashrc

# Expose Node Manager default port, and also default for admin and managed server 
EXPOSE $NM_PORT $ADMIN_PORT $MS_PORT $DEBUG_PORT

WORKDIR $DOMAIN_HOME

# Define default command to start bash. 
CMD ["startWLDomain.sh"]
```

**Docker version:**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:44:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:44:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

netstat on machine2:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9002                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

netstat on managed server container:

```
tcp6       0      0 10.0.9.3:7002          :::*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a port mapping using `-p 9002:7002`. That means you can do `telnet localhost 9002` from the docker host to reach the respective container. The port exposed by the container is `7002` and therefore, if you are executing the command from one of your containers you need to do `telnet machine2 7002`.

Based on your input you might want to try:

```
docker service create \
  --name=service1 \
  --publish mode=host,target=7002,published=9002,protocol=tcp \
  ...
```

This creates a service (one instance) and publishes the port on the node that the task is deployed on (`mode=host`).

Comment: `telnet localhost 9002` works fine from **machine2**.

`7002` is the container port and I'm mapping it to `9002` on the host machine i.e. **machine2** , now when I do `telnet machine2 9002` from machine1 I get connection refused.

Comment: are you using docker swarm or just docker?

Comment: I'm using the built-in swarm `docker swarm init`

Comment: OK, in that case you could use `docker service create` to make your ports available externally to the swarm

Comment: But, doesn't that create all admin servers?.

I mean if I create a service let say `docker service create --name test -p 9001:8001 --replicas=3 12212-baseimage`, this will create 3 admin servers across all the machines right?

Comment: No, unfortunately that does not fit the requirement. 
We need to have Admin and Managed server structure.